# NPE when inserting blob into informix database

Tags: informix

When I want to insert blob into database I got this exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSmartBlob.IfxLoColInfo(IfxSmartBlob.java:313) ~[ifxjdbc.jar:?]
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSmBlob.i(IfxSmBlob.java:791) ~[ifxjdbc.jar:?]
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSmBlob.a(IfxSmBlob.java:520) ~[ifxjdbc.jar:?]
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxResultSet.b(IfxResultSet.java:295) ~[ifxjdbc.jar:?]
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxStatement.c(IfxStatement.java:1283) ~[ifxjdbc.jar:?]
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(IfxPreparedStatement.java:421) ~[ifxjdbc.jar:?]
        at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.pmiExecuteUpdate(WSJdbcPreparedStatement.java:1187) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
        at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(WSJdbcPreparedStatement.java:804) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
```

Is there a way how to solve what is wrong ? I try to google but no information founded about this exception

statement looks like:

`insert into my_table (col1, col2, col3, blob)  VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)`

I am using `informix db: 12.10.FC4`

**UPDATE:**

wnen I try it from standalone application like java or groovy it works. This exception just occurs when I want to insert blob from web application running on Websphere server  8.5.5.2

ddl:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  col1 CHAR(24)   not null,
  col2 VARCHAR(255)  not null,
  col3 CHAR(1) default '0' not null,
  blob_col blob not null
)
```

Groovy: script which works

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import groovy.sql.Sql

class sql {

static main(args) { 
println "START"


def sql = Sql.newInstance( 'url', 'user', 'pass', 'com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver' );
sql.connection.autoCommit = false

def ps = sql.connection.prepareStatement("insert into my_table (col1,col2,col3,blob_col) values(?,?,?,?)");
ps.setString(1, "1");
ps.setString(2, "1");
ps.setString(3, "1");
byte[] bytes = new byte[100];
ps.setBytes(4, bytes);

ps.execute()
ps.close()
fis.close()

sql.commit()
println "END"
}
}
```

UPDATE_2:

another weird exception. I really dont know what are our db specialist doing with this db

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.informix.jdbc.IfxUDT incompatible with com.informix.jdbc.IfxInteger
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSmartBlob.IfxLoOpen(IfxSmartBlob.java:494) ~[ifxjdbc.jar:?]
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxBblob.<init>(IfxBblob.java:77) ~[ifxjdbc.jar:?]
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSmBlob.toBytes(IfxSmBlob.java:1030) ~[ifxjdbc.jar:?]
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxResultSet.getBytes(IfxResultSet.java:1216) ~[ifxjdbc.jar:?]
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxResultSet.getBytes(IfxResultSet.java:1231) ~[ifxjdbc.jar:?]
        at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcResultSet.getBytes(WSJdbcResultSet.java:909) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
```

but I still wonder there is no information about this errors on google

Comment: Thanks for sharing code. It works with my Informix 11.50.FC4. On other your SO question: stackoverflow.com/questions/22662026/how-to-insert-byte-array-into-informix-blob/ I see that Informix reported strange problem when SQL statement started with space. Remove it and write us if it helps.

Comment: how are you doing it when you use WAS and a web application, when you experience the problem? what code you have then?

Comment: sorry copy/paste error :) this topic is also from me and this isnt problem now. Probably there is something strange with db which I dont understand because now I try same application on new db which just created and now it work. But I am really curious what is wrong with 1 dba adn why this exception occurs

Comment: did you use the same driver version with both standalone app and web app in WAS? There are [reports](ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/software/data/sw-library/informix/pubs/library/notes/relnotes/jdb0211r28.html) of "IFXSMARTBLOB, IFXLOCOLINFO does not work. It always returns NULL." in some driver versions.

Answer (score 0):

Can you create simple `test_blobs` table and insert into it some picture as in my Jython code:

```
# writing picture into blob
db = DriverManager.getConnection(db_url, usr, passwd)
blob = FileInputStream('picture.jpeg')
pstm = db.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO test_blobs (content) VALUES (?)")
pstm.setBinaryStream(1, blob)
rs = pstm.execute()
blob.close()

# reading just inserted blob
pstm = db.prepareStatement("SELECT content FROM test_blobs")
rs = pstm.executeQuery()
while (rs.next()):
    image_stream = rs.getBinaryStream(1)
    fout = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    while 1:
        b = image_stream.read()
        if b < 0:
            break
        fout.write(b)
    arr = fout.toByteArray()
    f = open('picture_from_blob.jpeg', 'wb')
    f.write(arr)
    f.close()
```

Also show us:

1. version of your JDBC driver,
2. table schema (Informix has at least 3 types of BLOBs)

Comment: I am using jdbc 3.5 informix driver and column is just blob. Another problem is when I created groovy script similar to your then It works without problem. NPE occurs just on my web applicaton when trying to insert blob and just with version 12.10.FC4. In version 12.10.FC2 everything works OK

Comment: JDBC 3.50 is a little old. I have just checked and IBM offers 4.10.JC4DE to download. Maybe upgrade will help.

Comment: I try also 4.1 but with no success

Comment: It seems like bug in the new database engine. Can you show us your code used in tests: table schema and groovy script?

Comment: I dont know how groovy script help you but I updated my question. Is there a way to ask IBM developers what are they doing on line 313 in class which throw exception ?

Comment: I do not the same db version as you but probably someone on SO can run your code on 12.10.FC4 and see if it raises the same exception.

Comment: If you work with Informix you probably have support from IBM. In case of such problems IBM Poland was able to help me.